# Elements of a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am supposed to determine how many elements the following sets have and which they are for the following two:

```
(a) {∅, {∅}, {{∅}}, {∅, {∅}}, {{∅}, ∅}, {{∅}, {∅}}}
(b) {1} ∪ {1, 1} ∪ {1, {1}, 1} ∪ {1, {1, 1}, 1} ∪ {1, {1, {1}, 1}, 1}
```

a) I would say it has 5, the lements being "∅","{∅}","{{∅}}","{∅, {∅}}, "{{∅}, {∅}}"

b) This one is harder, but I would say that it has 3, the elements being "1", "{1}", "{1, 1}"

Are they correct, and if not, could someone please explain how to do them correctly?

Comment: In (a) note that $\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$ and $\{\{\emptyset\},\emptyset\}$ are equal. They are the same element.

Comment: For b): $\{1,1\}=\{1\}$ and $\{1,\{1\},1\}=\{1,\{1\}\}$.